# R Change point and CI colour in plot_summs or ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a coefficient plot which currently looks like this:

```
library(ggsci)
library(ggprism)
library(jtools)

Plot_1 <- plot_summs(list(treatment.report.mod, treatment.report.ac.mod, treatment.report.year.mod), 
           inner_ci_level = .9, point.shape = FALSE)

Plot_1 + theme_prism() +
  xlab("Coefficient estimate") + ylab("") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) + scale_color_lancet() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", linetype = "solid"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "black", linetype = "solid"),
        prism.ticks.length.x = unit(10, "pt"),
        axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold")) +
  scale_x_continuous(guide = "prism_minor",
                     minor_breaks = seq(-5, 5, 0.5)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0,
             colour = "grey80",
             linetype = 1) + 
                     scale_y_discrete(labels= c("Year", "Previous number of AC",
                                                "Treatment: Shots fired, dogs used",
                                                "Treatment: Shots fired, dogs not used", 
                                                "Previous number of reports"))
```

[image]

I would like to colour my coefficient estimates (instead of being hallow/ transparent, they would have a solid colour) and make my CIs black.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Unfortunately the data can't be shared due to some privacy agreements.

Comment: @Gab_Laj if you can't provide the data, it's considered good etiquette to provide a fake one, perhaps using an inbuilt dataset such as ``mtcars`` or ``iris``, or making your own.